# Access Custom Attribute from within an Editor Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is it possible to access a custom attribute on a property from within an editor template for that property?

For example, I have a simple class with a custom property:

```
public class MyClass
{
   [MyCustomAttribute("myCustomValue")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I then have an editor template for `string` and I would like to check that the string property has that custom attribute.

I've tried accessing the type and `CustomAttributes` from the view, but that won't work when the instance of the model is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using the following code in my editor template to get the value of a property from an attribute

```
var Member = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.GetMember(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName);
var Attribute = Member[0].GetCustomAttribute<MyCustomAttribute>();
if(Attribute != null)
{
    <p>@Attribute.MyProperty</p>
}
```

The code is a little rough and makes some assumptions, but you get the general idea.